# Virtual physics labs and state machines

Tags: state, simulator, state-machine

I would like to implement some virtual physics labs (simulator). For example, series and parallel connection of conductors (measurement of amperage and voltage).

But the main limitation is that I should use finite state machine for implementation (I am going to use State Pattern). Does someone have idea how I can use "finite state machine" in this case or offer some other application of state machine in physics labs? I'll be happy if there will be many states:-)

Thanks.

Comment: I know physics; I know DC circuits; I know state machines.  But I don't see where they fit together.  Voting to close unless you can clarify.

Comment: are we talking "new kind of science"?

Comment: My opinion is that finite state machine is not applicable in this case. But some other peoples consider that we can use FSM (may be for user's actions (assembly of the circuit) or a direct usage in circuit). Of course I can apply it to simulate but this way will be not good solution. Any objections?

Answer (score 0):

Try JFLAP
http://www.jflap.org/

Very user friendly and simple. 
It lets you simulate FSMs, and almost all the other things you come across in formal computer science. But its not really adapted for physics or such.